# get touch location scrollView

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I need get touch location, and I created an method to get it.. but when I touch in my ScrollView, the method dont return the location, only out of scrollView.

this is the code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint pos = [touch locationInView:nil];
    NSLog(@"Position of touch: %.0f, %.0f", pos.x, pos.y);
}
```

someone knows how to do it?
thanks!

Comment: Can you describe what object this method belongs to? Is it a custom gesture recognizer which you added to the scrollview (or a superview of the scrollview)? Or is it a custom scrollview?

Comment: i`s a custom scrollview, where will have same images.. when the use touch the image, I wanna know the touch`s position.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGPoint pos = [touch locationInView:nil];
```

You are retrieving the coordinates of the touch with respect to the window's origin. Per the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006785-CH3-SW5):

> *view*
>
> The view object in whose coordinate system you want the touch
>   located. A custom view that is handling the touch may specify self to
>   get the touch location in its own coordinate system. **Pass `nil` to get
>   the touch location in the window’s coordinates.**

To get the coordinates in your scroll view, you need to pass `self`:

```
CGPoint pos = [touch locationInView:self];
```